# Loading with int 13h 02h works fine in qemu and bochs, but not on hardware

Tags: assembly, x86-16, boot, bootloader

I've got this relatively simple boot loader that uses int 13h to load one sector from disk, the sector consists almost entirely of 0s save for the first byte which is an 'X'. The program is meant to load that second sector to 0x7e00 and then print out the first byte, an X, using int 10h 0eh. This works just fine in qemu and bochs but not when I load it onto a USB, in which case it doesn't print anything but it *does* move the cursor to the right. Printing data that is loaded alongside the boot sector works fine on hardware, and copying the program off the USB and running it in qemu also works fine so I know I'm not messing up when loading the data. I also checked the carry flag for an error in more complicated versions, and even ran a program that used int 13h 08h to learn about the disk's actual construction.

At this point I'm completely at a loss.

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
jmp 0:main

BOOT_DRIVE: db 0

main:
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    ; Setup registers
    mov bx, 0
    mov ds, bx
    mov es, bx
    mov fs, bx
    mov gs, bx

    ; Setup stack
    mov ss, bx
    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

    ; Read sectors from disk
    mov ah, 0x02

    mov ch, 0 ; Cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0 ; Head 0
    mov cl, 2 ; Sector 2

    mov al, 1 ; Read 1 sector

    mov bx, sec2 ; Read to sec2 (will end up at 0x7e00)

    int 0x13 ; Interrupt

    ; Display first loaded byte
    mov ah, 0x0e

    mov al, [sec2]
    int 0x10

    hlt

; Pad to end of first sector
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

; Data in second sector.
sec2:
    db 'X'

; Pad to end of second sector
times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

Comment: Try adding a valid BPB.

Comment: I see two possibilities.  `int 0x10/AH=0x0E` wants `BH` to be the display page to show the character one.  Or since you're just writing the character and not the attribute, if the current attribute is 0 you'll write a black-on-black character.

Comment: Yeah checking that you can write something to the screen first is a good idea.